# Rename command in Ubuntu: change character after date only when date at the beginning of the filename

Tags: linux, ubuntu, regular-expression, rename

For example this example with a date (my dates change, but they have always the format `YYYY-MM-DD`) and a trailing `-`:

```
2022-04-28-examplename-some-more-text-2022-04-28-more-text.txt
```

should become the date with a trailing `_`:

```
2022-04-28_examplename-some-more-text-2022-04-28-more-text.txt
```

But:

```
examplename-2022-04-28-some-more.txt
```

Should stay:

```
examplename-2022-04-28-some-more.txt
```

because the date is not standing at the beginning of the filename.

For other renames (like ä to ae) I used a command that renamed files in all sub-directories of current directory and it worked great.

```
$ find . -depth -exec rename 's/\ä/ae/g' {} +
```

How must I change that command?

Comment: How can we know what files need to be renamed? Can we assume that ***all*** files whose name starts with *exactly* 4 numbers, then a `-`, then *exactly* 2 numbers, another `-` and then *exactly* 2 numbers followed by a `-` need to be renamed? Or can you have other formats? For example, can you have `22-04-28-` instead of `2022-04-28-`? Can you have `123760123-` (numbers, but not a date)?

Comment: All files that starts with YYYY-MM-DD- need to be renamed.

Comment: Yes, but is `9999-67-65-` a "YYYY-MM-DD-"? How about `0000-00-00-`? Do we need to check that the numbers are valid dates, or is it enough to just look for numbers?

Comment: Oh, it is enough to check for valid numbers (if they are on the beginning of a file name). So `9999-67-65-` (but there wouldn't exist such a string, would also be renamed to `9999-67-65_`.